# Cumulative Binning of Vectors/Features

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Suppose, If there is a feature vector of length n then on cumulative binning into k bins, the feature vector length now becomes nxk. How exactly can that be done? Any help?

I have come across this cumulative binning concept for the first time under section VII on page 8 in the paper :[Learning Human Activities and Object Affordances from RGB-D Videos](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.1207.pdf)

I have contacted authors of the paper regarding this, but haven't received any reply from them yet.

When can such a technique be useful? Are there any other applications of this technique?

Answer (score 0):

As for how to combine feature into a matrix it is simple

M = numpy.vstack((f1,f2,...,fk))

As for why cumulative binning is necessary. It is because they have ten classes in all (neck, torso, left shoulder, left elbow, left palm, right
shoulder, right elbow and right palm)
 So each bin corresponds to one class
Hope it can help

Comment: I don't think that 10 is because of that, as the same cumulative binning is being used at object features (which don't have any of those neck, torso,....right elbow and right palm)... It could be because of cumulative binning may have helped in reducing the sparsity of features when collected at such high dimensions. This could be the reason in this paper. I am not sure when and where is this method used generally though